# What is the path to the blockchain for a pruned node in the GUI wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, nodes, ubuntu, pruning

I went to the advanced section for the GUI and set the path for the node as:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ls -hal Monero/lmdb/
total 11G
drwx------ 2 nicholas nicholas 4.0K Jun  5 00:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 nicholas nicholas 4.0K Jun  5 01:17 ..
-rw------- 1 nicholas nicholas  11G Jun  5 08:11 data.mdb
-rw------- 1 nicholas nicholas 8.0K Jun  5 08:11 lock.mdb
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

1.)  How do I confirm that the node is pruned?  I have limited storage and have [enabled](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/11454/14165) the flag to prune the node.

2.)  I think there's a "default" node elsewhere, but where?

3.)  Is this even the blockchain?  I was [expecting](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/11359/14165) something like a ".bitmonero" folder.

---

update:  Only because the sync was stalled I removed the custom path and set to the default location.  Since then the sync is about halfway complete, visually on the GUI progress bar, and that `data.mdb` file hasn't increased in size.  *Where is the default location for the blockchain and other node data?*  I've looked through the log but don't know quite what to filter for.

Answer (score 1):

> Where is the default location for the blockchain and other node data?

Generally it is in ~/.bitmonero directory.

Comment: I'll take another look but didn't see it.